# How do I detect click on model instance in Libgdx?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I have simple 3D model in my application. I'm wondering if it's possible to detect click on a model instance. I've creaded model and model instance objects. Then I render it and it can be seen on the screen.

1. Is there a way to set some kind of click listener for this model/model instance?
   (or something with similar functionality)
2. I've tried this thing: `if(Intersector.intersectRaySphere(ray, modelInstancePosition, modelInstanceRadius , null ))` but unfortunately it works if there is only one model on the stage. When we put two models, one behind another, it picks both model instances. How do I detect the one that has been actually clicked?

Comment: For accurate results you will probably have to use bullet.

Comment: measure the distance between the camera position and both of the modelInstancePosition and choose the closer one.